# How to fetch last row data of a gridview asp.net c #

Tags: asp.net

I want to fetch the last row data of a gridview and accordingly change colour of each cell depending on its value.
Your help will be deeply appreciated.Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

If "last row" means footer:

```
GridViewRow footer = grid.FooterRow;
```

Otherwise:

```
GridViewRow lastRow = grid.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Last();
```

Now you can loop `lastRow.Cells` or use `lastRow.DataItem` if it was databound recently.